# Could not resolve <local:chatters> to a component implementation

Tags: flash, apache-flex, compiler-errors, adobe, xml-namespaces

My flex source folder 'src' has these files:

```
src/
  chatters.as
  chatters.mxml
  main.as
  main.mxml
```

This is the source of 'chatters.mxml':

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"  
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
         xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
         width="250" height="200"
         contentBackgroundColor="#abcdef">
</s:Group>
```

This is the source of 'main.mxml':

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                       xmlns:local="*"
                       applicationComplete="run();">    
    <local:chatters>        
    </local:chatters>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

All the files chatters.as, chatters.mxml, main.as, main.mxml are under default package, and the XML namespace for default package is set as xmlns:local="*" in main.mxml.

However, I get the error message: **Could not resolve <local:chatters> to a component implementation** when creating 'chatters' component in main.mxml.

Everything is in default package, xmlns already defined, how come flash builder shows me such error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it's getting confused about which class to use. Your `src/` directory seems to have a `chatters.as` and `chatters.mxml`. Each one of these is defining a class named `chatters`.

I just tried to create an Actionscript class with the same name of an MXML document, but Flash Builder would not let me. Hoping there's an interesting story about how you did that :)

Flash builder gets confused when 2 files .as and .mxml with the same name in the same folder.

Comment: the file 'chatters.as' has no class definition, only functions, so it may not have this conflict i think

Comment: i created the file chatters.mxml first, maybe that's the mistery?

Comment: YES! your answer indirectly solves the problem, tks! not allowed to have .as and .mxml with the same name in the same folder, or flash builder gets confused